# Finding appropriate parent with jQuery

Tags: jquery, dom, parent

Given a DOM element how do I find its nearest parent with a given css class?

```
$(".editButton").click(function() {
   (magic container selector goes here).addClass("editing");
});
```

I don't want to use lots or $(...).parent().parent() since I don't want to be bound to a particular dom structure.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This should work

```
$(this).parents('.classYouWant:first').addClass("editing");
```

Comment: Am I not right in thinking that all jquery functions actually return a list. If so, you might want to do $(this).parents('.classYouWant:first') (try it!)

Comment: @Jennifer: You are correct, if the element had more than 1 parent it would set editing to all of them.  You should have posted an answer. I'd accept it.

Comment: so :first, in this example, gets the nearest parent to $(this) with .classYouWant? so working it's way UP the DOM?

Answer (score 11):

```
$( this ).closest( '.yourselector' )
```

As the name tells, finds the closest ancestor for `this` element.

Comment: +1 This one is my preference, when I know I'm only after 1 element

Answer (score 3):

Use `.parents(".yourClass")` instead of `.parent()`.

[jQuery parents()](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/parents#expr)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the parent selection. eg `$(".myclass:parent").something();` will find all the elements with the class myclass that have children.

Comment: Although correct, it doesn't address the question since it's not find the parent for a particular dom element.